# Complex Analysis (Complex Mapping) stuck on professor's method of simplification in math notes

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm having an exam this university semester and need some help with my math notes. I've come accross some problems with the section "Complex Mapping."

Link to Image of my Notes: [Click Me (see first image, red circled area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FzSF.jpg)

I have given access to the part of the notes that I'm struggling with, with the exact part I don't quite get **circled in red** (its in the 1st image). The second image is actually the first part of the lecture notes, prior to the page I'm having problems with, its there incase you need to read the whole thing.

Within the circled area I don't quite understand why the professor has claimed

> "We have now two equations for 4 quantities, therefore two of them can be chosen arbitrary. Let us take $b_x = b_y = 0$, so..".

Is that a rule and if so could I have an explanation as to how that rule works and why it applies here? Also how does he get from the part just before the area I circled in red, to the simplified form below it.

You may check to the notes on the page before this by checking the second image although I highly doubt it's needed, I must be missing a rule or simplification process.

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like I'd need some more context, like what problem exactly is being solved. From the notes it seems like he is simply picking $b$ to be the origin, simplifying things.